# Is Blazor app with Open ID Connect supported by Azure App Service Containers?

Tags: azure, docker, blazor, asp.net-blazor

**Problem**
We are getting the following error in the browser after deploying Blazor webassembly app as an App Service Container:

```
AuthenticationService.js:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://YYY.azurewebsites.net/authentication/login?returnUrl=https%3A%2F%2FYYY.azurewebsites.net%2Ffetchdata' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://YYY.azurewebsites.net/.well-known/openid-configuration'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Wondering if docker deployment is supported in Blazor at this moment, if yes, how can we fix this?

**Steps to re-pro:**
 1. In VS 2019 Professional preview Version 16.7.0 Preview 2.0: create Blazor app (standard "Blazor WebAssembly App" template) with Hosted option on and in-app authentication with Identity Server
 2. Deploy linux docker container to Azure Web App for containers service (B1) 
 3. HTTPS Only setting is ON for the App Service

We are using the following simple docker file for that:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AppNameHere.Server.dll"]
```

Somehow OIDC JS library used by Blazor is not picking up the fact that we are runnig over HTTPS (although HTTP is used between the container instance and App service load balancer).

Answer (score 1):

You should either :

- Install an HTTPS certificate for your endpoint and run a full end-to-end HTTPS (Recommended)
  To setup kestrel with a certificate on docker read [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-https?view=aspnetcore-3.1)
- Override the OIDC config used by your app :

**Create a metadata.json file**

```
{
    "issuer": "http://YYY.azurewebsites.net",
    "jwks_uri": "https://YYY.azurewebsites.net/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks",
    "authorization_endpoint": "https://YYY.azurewebsites.net/connect/authorize",
    "token_endpoint": "https://YYY.azurewebsites.net/connect/token",
    "userinfo_endpoint": "https://YYY.azurewebsites.net/connect/userinfo",
    "end_session_endpoint": "https://YYY.azurewebsites.net/connect/endsession",
    "check_session_iframe": "https://YYY.azurewebsites.net/connect/checksession"
}
```

> "issuer": "http://YYY.azurewebsites.net" is an HTTP url not HTTPS

**Configure the application to get metadata from your custom file**

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");
        builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication<RemoteAuthenticationState, RemoteUserAccount>(options =>
                {
                    var providerOptions = options.ProviderOptions;
                    providerOptions.Authority = "https://YYY.azurewebsites.net";
                    providerOptions.MetadataUrl = "https://YYY.azurewebsites.net/metadata.json";
                    providerOptions.PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://YYY.azurewebsites.net/authentication/logout-callback";
                    providerOptions.RedirectUri = "https://YYY.azurewebsites.net/login-callback";
                });
        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Appreciated! When we tried to run e2e https we faced a small problem - web app would not publish https port for docker container, it publishes the only http port, is there any way to overcome this? (Https port is exposed in dockerfile)

Comment: Yes : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-https?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Can you point to any resources where it says that full end-to-end HTTPS is a recommended approach? I'd like to learn more about pros & cons. Also, how do we deal with certificates - would it be possible to reuse the app service managed one or I'd have to create a new one?

Comment: Regarding end-to-end HTTPS :  https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032

Comment: Regarding Azure certificate management I don't have enough skills